# CPU overhead for struct?

Tags: c++, c

In C/C++, is there any CPU overhead for acessing struct members in comparison to isolated variables?

For a concrete example, should something like the first code sample below use more CPU cycles than the second one? Would it make any difference if it were a class instead of a struct? (in C++)

1)

```
struct S {
    int a;
    int b;
};

struct S s;
s.a = 10;
s.b = 20;    
s.a++;
s.b++;
```

2)

```
int a;
int b;
a = 10;
b = 20;
a++;
b++;
```

Comment: Not enough for it to matter for your code.  It's a micro-optimization; maybe even a nano-optimization.

Comment: No, the second shouldn't really ever be used in favor of the first. A good compiler will write equally optimized code.

Comment: Why don't you just take a peak at the disassambly?  Also, many people here are just going to cry "Premature optimization!" and ignore your question.

Comment: Compiler should generate identical code. Why would it make a difference if this was a class?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Well there are guarantees about memory layout for the struct version, which do not hold for the standalone variables.

Comment: How would memory layout affect the CPU overhead? Memory overhead, perhaps, but not CPU overhead as such (unless the difference is large enough to affect caching, possibly). But in general, no matter which, the spacing will most likely be the same either way.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

"Don't optimize yet."  The compiler will figure out the best case for you.  Write what makes sense first, and make it faster later if you need to.  For fun, I ran the following in Clang 3.4 (-O3 -S):

```
void __attribute__((used)) StructTest() {
  struct S {
      int a;
      int b;
  };

  volatile struct S s;
  s.a = 10;
  s.b = 20;    
  s.a++;
  s.b++;
}
void __attribute__((used)) NoStructTest() {
  volatile int a;
  volatile int b;
  a = 10;
  b = 20;    
  a++;
  b++;
}

int main() {
  StructTest();
  NoStructTest();
}
```

`StructTest` and `NoStructTest` have identical ASM output:

```
pushl   %ebp
movl    %esp, %ebp
subl    $8, %esp
movl    $10, -4(%ebp)
movl    $20, -8(%ebp)
incl    -4(%ebp)
incl    -8(%ebp)
addl    $8, %esp
popl    %ebp
ret
```

Comment: X86 isn't the only architecture around there.

Comment: @hivert I actually ran this on a 16-bit MCU first, and it was also identical in the two cases.  I just figured people would recognize x86.

Answer (score 4):

No. The size of all the types in the `struct`, and thus the offset to each member from the beginning of the `struct`, is known at compile-time, so the address used to fetch the values in the `struct` is every bit as knowable as the addresses of individual variables.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that all of the values in a struct are adjacent in memory, and are better able to take advantage of the memory caching than the variables.

The variables are probably adjacent in memory too, but they're not guaranteed to be adjacent like the struct.

---

That being said, cpu performance should not be a consideration when deciding whether to use or not use a struct in the first place.

Comment: That's wrong but right, if you get my meaning : Yes, compilers *must* place struct members adjacently in memory, but they are free to put statics and locals anywhere they choose. This freedom *could* allow optimizers to move and reorder variables for better performance than the fixed struct ordering allows, based on analysis of their usage. I'm not sure if any compiler does this today, but in general, the more freedom the optimizer has, the better a job it can do.

Comment: @Roddy Structs can actually be chopped up by compilers and reordered, but the compiler needs to be certain that you won't need use it in a way that requires that property.  Local structs get this treatment naturally, but global structs typically need heavy link-time optimization to get cut up.

Answer (score 0):

The real answer is: It completely depend on you CPU architecture and your compiler. The best way is to compile and look at the assembly code.

Now for x86 machine, I'm pretty sure there isn't. The offset is computed as compile time and there is an adressing mode with some offset.

Comment: On which CPU would it make a difference then?

Comment: @jalf I'm not an expert in computer architecture but I can imagine that on very basic risc machine with only simple adressing, this could induce more operation.

Comment: An optimizing compiler will likely turn them into the same thing before it even hits the code generation for the CPU/MCU.

Comment: This isn't true if you start to play with pointer on structure which is the case most of the time where you use struct. It is indeed true in The OP use case, but it is not a realistic use case.

Comment: That's outside of the scope of this question I think, but in any case `-flto` has some serious firepower and can cut structures into pieces.  This would turn the above struct into two `int`'s for all intents and purposes.

Comment: @Sam Cristall : then we didn't understood the question the same way. I'm pretty sure that on a very simple RISC architecture with only direct and indirect adresing mode, if you have a function `f(struct S *x)` compared to `f(int *a, int *b)` there is a slight overhead (one more instruction) when accessing `x->b`.

Comment: I maintain a backend for a [simple RISC](http://www.elevenengineering.com/documents/IG/XInC%20Programmers%20Card_DO1103.pdf) with Clang/LLVM so I ran this and checked the output.  It was identical in both cases.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49430/discussion-between-sam-cristall-and-hivert)

Comment: @hivert there is no reason why, on any CPU architecture, there would be a difference in performance. In both cases, the offset is known at compile-time.

Answer (score -1):

If you ask the compiler to optimize (e.g. compile with `gcc -O2` or `g++ -O2`) then there are no much overhead (probably too small to be measurable, or perhaps a few percents).

However, if you use only local variables, the optimizing compiler might even not allocate slots for them in the local [call frame](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack).

Compile with `gcc -O2 -fverbose-asm -S`  and look into the generated assembly code.

Using a `class` won't make any difference (of course, some `class`-es have costly constructors & destructors).

Such a code could be useful in generated C or C++ code (like [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) does); local such `struct`-s or `class`-es contain the local call frame (as seen by the MELT language, see e.g. its [gcc/melt/warmelt-genobj+01.cc](http://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/branches/melt-branch/gcc/melt/generated/warmelt-genobj+01.cc?view=log) generated file). I don't claim it is as efficient as real C++ local variables, but it gets optimized enough.

Comment: Or even more, I've seen some local struct entirely stored in register.